# Find $f(x)$ using Mean Value Theorem.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given $f:\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(0)=3$ and

$$f'(x) + 2f(x) = 4 -8x \quad      x\in \mathbb{R}$$

What is $f(x)$?

Many thanks!

Comment: i think this is a differential equation

Answer (score 0):

in a first step solve the equation $$f'(x)+2f(x)=0$$ with $$f(x)=e^{\lambda x}$$

Comment: thanks but next step?

Comment: the next step is to find a Special solution of the inhomogeneous equation for your Control it is $$4(x-1)$$